# How to use contents of one array to set contents of other array to true in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got two javascript arrays. One default array:

```
propertyTypes = [
    {key:'OFFICE', value:false},
    {key:'RESIDENTIAL', value:false},
    {key:'RETAIL', value:false},
    {key:'INDUSTRIAL', value:false},
    {key:'HOTEL', value:false}
];
```

and another array which looks like this:

```
property_types: [
    {
        "type": "OFFICE"
    },
    {
        "type": "RETAIL"
    }
]
```

I now want to set all the values in the first array to `true` which occur in the second array as a type so that the first array will look like this:

```
propertyTypes = [
    {key:'OFFICE', value:true},  // so this one should be true
    {key:'RESIDENTIAL', value:false},
    {key:'RETAIL', value:true},  // and this one
    {key:'INDUSTRIAL', value:false},
    {key:'HOTEL', value:false}
];
```

I had some ideas about using some kind of double nested loop, but none of them seem to make any sense.

Does anybody know how I can do this in a logical way? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Do you need to retain order for propertyTypes?

Comment: The way you have the data structured you need to iterate over both arrays. Why didn't your solution work? Please post it.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use [`arr.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to achieve this.
>   The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

Try this:

```js
var propertyTypes = [{
  key: 'OFFICE',
  value: false
}, {
  key: 'RESIDENTIAL',
  value: false
}, {
  key: 'RETAIL',
  value: false
}, {
  key: 'INDUSTRIAL',
  value: false
}, {
  key: 'HOTEL',
  value: false
}];
var property_types = [{
  "type": "OFFICE"
}, {
  "type": "RETAIL"
}];
propertyTypes.map(function(item) {
  for (var i = 0, iLen = property_types.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    if (property_types[i].type == item.key) {
      item.value = true;
      break;
    }
  }
});
alert(JSON.stringify(propertyTypes));
```

Answer (score 0):

A double for loop is the way to do it. Here's a simple example:

```
var propertyTypesOut = [];
for (var i = propertyTypes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var found = false;
    for (var j = property_types.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (propertyTypes[i].key === property_types[j].type) {
            var found = true;
            break;
        }
    };
    propertyTypesOut.push({
        key: propertyTypes[i].key,
        value: found
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you need 2 fors, you can do it like this:

```
propertyTypes = [
{key:'OFFICE', value:false},
{key:'RESIDENTIAL', value:false},
{key:'RETAIL', value:false},
{key:'INDUSTRIAL', value:false},
{key:'HOTEL', value:false}
];

property_types= [
    {
        type: "OFFICE"
    },
    {
        type: "RETAIL"
    }
];

propertyTypes.forEach(function(pType) {
    for (index = 0; index < property_types.length; ++index) {
        if(pType.key==property_types[index].type){
            pType.value = true;
break;

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a first naive approach that should get you started.

```
var propertyTypes = [
    {key:'OFFICE', value:false},
    {key:'RESIDENTIAL', value:false},
    {key:'RETAIL', value:false},
    {key:'INDUSTRIAL', value:false},
    {key:'HOTEL', value:false}
];

var property_types = [
    {
        "type": "OFFICE"
    },
    {
        "type": "RETAIL"
    }
];

for (var i = 0; i < property_types.length; i++) {
    var key = property_types[i].type;
    for (var j = 0; j < propertyTypes.length; j++) {
        if (propertyTypes[j].key === key) {
            propertyTypes[j].value = true;
        }
    }
}

console.log(propertyTypes);
/* returns
[ { key: 'OFFICE', value: true },
  { key: 'RESIDENTIAL', value: false },
  { key: 'RETAIL', value: true },
  { key: 'INDUSTRIAL', value: false },
  { key: 'HOTEL', value: false } ]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are iterating through arrays, `for` loops should work.

Also,

```
property_types: [...]
```

should be:

```
property_types = [...]
```

```js
var propertyTypes = [
        {key:'OFFICE', value:false},
        {key:'RESIDENTIAL', value:false},
        {key:'RETAIL', value:false},
        {key:'INDUSTRIAL', value:false},
        {key:'HOTEL', value:false}
    ]
,   property_types = [
            {"type": "OFFICE"}
        ,
            {"type": "RETAIL"}
    ]
,   result = '';
for(first = 0; first < propertyTypes.length; first ++) {
    var firstType = propertyTypes[first];
    for (second = 0; second < property_types.length; second ++) {
        if(firstType['key'] == property_types[second]['type']) {
            firstType['value'] = true;
        }
    }
    result += firstType['key'] + ' : ' + firstType['value'] + '<br/>';
}
document.write(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var propertyTypes = [
    ...
];
var property_types = [
    ...
];
var sel_ptypes = [];

property_types.forEach(function (a, i){
    sel_ptypes[i++] = a['type'];
});

propertyTypes.forEach(function(a){
    a.value = sel_ptypes.indexOf(a.key) !== -1;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/34j86uo1/2